# How to load videos before displaying them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, video-streaming

I have a video player component that has an array of videos stored in the public folder. Right now I play them one by one in a loop, when one ends the next one starts, but there is a slight delay between the two. How could I load the next video before it starts playing, so that there is no transitional delay?

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

class Player extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            current: 0,
            videos: [
                "/Videos/video_1.mp4",
                "/Videos/video_2.mp4",
                "/Videos/video_3.mp4"
            ]
        }
    }

    onEnd = () => {
        if (this.state.current + 1 === this.state.videos.length) {
            this.setState({ current: 0 });
        } else {
            this.setState({ current: this.state.current + 1 });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <video
                    src={this.state.videos[this.state.current]}
                    autoPlay
                    controls
                    onEnded={this.onEnd}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Player;
```

Comment: I haven't tried that, but what you could try is before the one video ends you could add a new `video` tag that is not visible to the DOM, with a `preload` attribute and the URL of the next video. And as soon as `onEnded` triggers, swap the visibility.

Comment: So something like "when 1 second of the video is left" to create a new video tag with opacity = 0.0001 (something very low) with preload, and when the first video ends set opacity to 1?

Comment: Something like that. I'm not sure when `preload` will trigger. If the existence in the DOM is sufficient, or if it needs to be actually visible. Maybe you can place it behind the other `video` tag. Maybe `display: none` will work. Maybe using a position with `fixed` and `left` to a large negative value. Just try various ways to see which one works reliable across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have each `video` element for each source, instead of switch it for one element.

Then left only 1 video element visible, others hidden.

And after the video element finished playing, make the next element visible and start playing.